# Threads conflict in some cases, in loop conditions

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on a project that uses Threads. In some cases, I have these problems:

Here is some piece of my code :

```
List<EmailAddress> lstEmailAddress = new List<EmailAddress>();
private void TimerCheckInternetConnection_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (TicketLock)
    {
        if (UtilityManager.CheckForInternetConnection())
        {
            if (ApplicationRunStatus == Enum_ApplicationRunStatus.UnknownDisconnect || ApplicationRunStatus == Enum_ApplicationRunStatus.IsReady)
            {
                // Connect
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lstEmailAddress.Count; i++)
                    {
                        lstEmailAddress[i].IsActive = lstEmailAddress[i].Login();
                    }

                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        // some code

                    }));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is EmailAddress class :

```
class EmailAddress
{
    private Imap4Client imap = new Imap4Client();
    private object objectLock = new object();

    public bool IsActive;
    public string Address;
    public string Password;

    public string RecieveServerAddress;
    public int RecieveServerPort;

    public bool Login()
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            try
            {
                imap.ConnectSsl(RecieveServerAddress, RecieveServerPort);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                imap.Login(Address, Password);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And my problem is this:

When I want to use `Login` procedure that belongs to `EmailAddress` Class, it has some conflict. As you can see, I used `Lock` but any thing changed.

For more details:
If I have 3 items in `lstEmailAddress` , the Login procedure has to be called 3 times by this code. but every time, the login procedure will work on same username and password. So all my emails cannot login correctly.
If I remove threadpool, it will be ok.

Comment: You queue up actions for the threadpool inside the lock, but there is no guarantee they will *execute* while you have the lock. The threadpool actions need to lock themselves.

Comment: so do u suggest I to remove lock ? @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: @Elahe **no** ... you should pull your `lock` inside the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => { ... } ` block (... most likely around the `for` there and maybe another one inside the `BeginInvoke`...)

Comment: I did it but the problem has not solved @CarstenKönig

Comment: IMO the problem is with your class itself - there is no need to make the `IsActive` property public and you should take care for it's operations to be thread-safe - this problem is almost impossible to *debug* from just seeing this tiny part of your system

Comment: In cause you don't understand: the complete `Login` part (at best) should be a single (external - not in email) method without mutable state that just takes `(username, password)` and returns (if successful) some kind of token - if you like you can make this an `Task<Token>` too - but don't mix this into your email-class with unprotected mutable states that can be changed by public setters - this is a recipe for desaster

Comment: Isn't the lock for the EmailAddress useless? It is created for each instance of email address and the lock(objectLock) does nothing? Unless called again from another thread obviously, but I don't see why that would be so.

Comment: Multithreaded code is not just about sprinkling locks all over the place, you need to have a deep understanding of how multithreading works, the pitfalls, the tools at your disposal (locks, events, different collection types, etc.). If you don't have that, my best advice would be to not write multithreaded code.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? In .NET 4.5 you don't need to use the threadpool explicitly or use BeginInvoke. Moreover, the concurrent collections in .NET 4+ eliminate the need for locking when modifying collections

Comment: What is ImapClient? Perhaps it already supports async operations either as tasks or as Begin/End operations, eg BeginConnectSsl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very confusing:

1. If you add the `lock` in your code, it will run synchroniously, only one thread at the time, which will lead to performance loss.
2. If you queue work via `QueueUserWorkItem` - it will run in other thread, and **not inside `TicketLock`**
3. You should incapsulate locks inside your class, and should not lock entire logic in your program.
4. You start work for a loop variable `i`, which is [being closured for it's last value](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx), which lead for a problem you state in last sentence.
5. `lock` object in `Email` class isn't `static` so it's being created for each instance, and doesn't actually lock anithing.
6. As you are using `Invoke` method, your code is being started from UI, and you need to pass the synchronization context. I suggest you to use [`TPL` code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for this, and do not directly work with [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx)

So I suggest you this solution:

```
List<EmailAddress> lstEmailAddress = new List<EmailAddress>();
private void TimerCheckInternetConnection_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove this lock as we have another in Email class
    //lock (TicketLock)
    if (UtilityManager.CheckForInternetConnection())
    {
        if (ApplicationRunStatus == Enum_ApplicationRunStatus.UnknownDisconnect
          || ApplicationRunStatus == Enum_ApplicationRunStatus.IsReady)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstEmailAddress.Count; i++)
            {
                // use local variable to store index
                int localIndex = i;
                // Connect
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                {
                    // if you add a lock here, this will run synchroniosly,
                    // and you aren't really need the ThreadPool
                    //lock (TicketLock)
                    lstEmailAddress[localIndex].IsActive = lstEmailAddress[localIndex].Login();

                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        // some code
                    }));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

class EmailAddress
{
    // if you have to login only for one user simultaneosly
    // use static variables here, other wise simply remove the lock as it is useless
    private static Imap4Client imap;

    private static object objectLock;
    // static constructor for only one initialization for a static fields
    static EmailAddress()
    {
        objectLock = new object();
        imap = new Imap4Client();
    }

    public bool IsActive;
    public string Address;
    public string Password;

    public string RecieveServerAddress;
    public int RecieveServerPort;

    public bool Login()
    {
        // aquire a static lock
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            try
            {
                imap.ConnectSsl(RecieveServerAddress, RecieveServerPort);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // STORE THE EXCEPTION!!!
                // return as you haven't connected
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                imap.Login(Address, Password);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // STORE THE EXCEPTION!!!
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Change your Code as and try .  you code is queing item from lstEmailAddress where it will always go and hit last item from the list. change your code to inquie each item in threadpool. that should fix. it.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < lstEmailAddress.Count; i++)
     { 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                         {
                            lstEmailAddress[i].IsActive = lstEmailAddress[i].Login();
                         }   
    }
```

Comment: why? What would this change besides giving even more places where the lock would be needed?

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in the original code: The most imporant one is that each thread in the queue works through all items (this is fixed in this answer). However there are additional errors with incorrect locking all over the place.

Comment: `i` variable should be copied to local